# Closed subspace of vector space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I would like to know where the problem is in the following proof that every finite-dimensional subspace $F$ of a normed vector space $E$ is closed.

Let $(u_n)\in F^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence converging to $l$ and $(e^1,\ldots,e^p)$ be a basis of $F$.

We have, for all $n$, 
$$
u_n = x_n^1e^1+\ldots x_n^p e^p 
$$
and it converges to 
$$
 x_\star^1e^1+\ldots x_\star^p e^p =l
$$
which, obviously, belongs to $F$.

Comment: I don't understande what is the statement that you are trying to prove.

Comment: Show that every converging sequence of $F$ converges to $l\in  F$

Comment: Where’s the proof that $(x^k_n)$ converges?

Comment: @egreg: in a normed $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, a sequence $(x_n)_n$ converges if and only if the real valued sequence  $(x_n^k)_n$ (kth components of $x_n$) converges for all $k$.
So taking the limit in both sides, I do not assume that the limit has the form $x_\star^1e_1 + \ldots x_\star^pe_p$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is not correct, since it assumes that the limit of your sequence must be of the form$$x_\star^1e^1+\cdots+x_\star^ne^n,$$which is *exactly* what you are supposed to prove.