# Limit of vectors and limit of components

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, limits

This question is related to the (closed) topic :

[Closed subspace of vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630899/closed-subspace-of-vector-space)

Let $(u_n)\in F^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence converging to $l$ and $(e^1,\ldots,e^p)$ be a basis of $F$ (vector space).

There exists $(x_n)_n\in (\mathbb{R}^p)^\mathbb{N}$ so that for all $n$, 
$$
u_n = x_n^1e^1+\ldots x_n^p e^p. 
$$

Also $(u_n)$  converges if and only if all the real valued sequence of its components converge.

Then, denote by $x_\star^i$ the limit of $x_n^i,\, i=1\ldots p,$ and $u_\star$ the limit of $u_n$.

Then $u_\star = x_\star^1e^1+\ldots +x_\star^pe^p$.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: What does $x_n^1e^1$ mean?  $x_n^1$ and $e^1$ are vectors, aren't they?  How are you multiplying them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\R{\mathbb R}$
I see by looking at your other question that you intend $F$ to be a linear subspace of a real Euclidean space $E$.  $F$ then has a metric $||\cdot||$ induced by the metric on $E$, and you also give $F$ a fixed basis, which induces a vector space isomorphism $\phi :\R^p \to F$, where $p = \dim F$.

You ask in effect whether the following statements are true:

1. $F$ is closed in $E$.
2. $F$ is complete with respect to the metric inherited from $E$.
3. The vector space isomorphism  $\phi :\R^p \to F$ is a homeomorphism, where $\R^p$ is given the standard topology.
4. A sequence in $F$ converges if and only if its coordinate sequences with respect to the given basis converge.

Yes, all four statements are true and they are more or less equivalent.  There are several ways to go about proving this.  For example, you can go about it this way:  The norm on $F$ gives you a norm $||\cdot||'$ on $\R^p$ via $||x||' = ||\phi(x)||$.  It is a theorem that any two norms on $\R^p$ are equivalent, and convergence with respect to any norm on $\R^p$ is equivalent to co-ordinatewise convergence. This theorem implies statements 2, 3 and 4, and statement 1 is a consequence.

Addendum:  For the equivalence of all norms on a finite dimensional space, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2702434.  This uses compactness of the unit sphere with respect to one of your favorite norms.  Another approach to the whole problem would be to show statement (1) first, as follows.  Show that $E = F \oplus F^\perp$ and use finite dimensionality to show $F = (F^\perp)^\perp$.  Conclude from this that $F$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is not justified:

> Also $(u_n)$ converges if and only if all the real valued sequence of its components converge.

How would you prove it?

It is related to the question whether $l \in F$, which is precisely what you are trying to prove.

What you should try to prove is that the finite-dimensional space $F$ is *complete* (i.e. every Cauchy sequence converges). Then it will follow that $F$ is also closed.

Comment: if $u_n$ converges it has a limit $u$, which has a representation in the basis. It's quite obvious that the coordinates of the sequence will then converge to the coordinates of the limit. The other direction is the same.

Comment: @Thomas True, if the limit $u$ is in your space. That is precisely the issue here.

Comment: There is no space of set mentioned in which the limit or it's components is/are supposed to be. Without that the statement is simply true. "$u_n$ converges" is a statement about the existence of a llimit. That this does not imply additional properties like some set being closed is correct, but I do not see any of these in the (in my opinion) ill posed question.

Comment: Ok so this statement is not justified. And the only way to prove it is to prove that the set is closed ?

Comment: @Thomas The question is vague but I understood that $(u_n)_n$ is in the finite-dimensional space $F$, which converges to $u \in X$ ($X$ being the larger space of which $F$ is a subspace) and we're trying to prove that in fact $u \in F$. The OP wrote $u_n = x_n^1e^1+\cdots +x_n^p e^p$ and then appealed to the above statement and concluded that $$u = (\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^1) e^1 + \cdots + (\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^p)e^p \in F$$
without additional argumentation.

Comment: @Smilia You mean complete? I don't know if there is another way.